# One SQL query over three tables

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to query over three tables. Right now I have managed to join two tables. I'm doing my first databases, but right now I'm really stuck. Here are my tables

**Drivers**

```
|DRIVER_ID|FIRST_NAME|LAST_NAME|AGE|
|        1|John      |Smith    |19 |
|        2|Steve     |Oak      |33 |
|        3|Mary      |Sanchez  |22 |
```

**Drivers_in_Teams**

```
|DRIVERS_IN_TEAMS_ID|DRIVER_ID|TEAM_ID|BEG_DATE |END_DATE |CAR        |
|                  1|        1|      1|18-NOV-05|         |Toyota     |
|                  2|        3|      2|10-APR-12|         |Ford       |
|                  3|        2|      3|19-JUL-01|02-AUG-04|Volkswagen |
```

**Team**

```
|TEAM_ID  |NAME      |COUNTRY |
|        1|Turbo     |Sweden  |
|        2|Rally     |UK      |
|        3|Baguette  |France  |
```

BEG_DATEs are done with "sysdate-number"

My goal is to find a driver, who is driving a Ford and still has a valid contract (END_DATE is not set)

I would like to make a query over three tables, so the result should display a drivers FIRST NAME, LAST NAME and a COUNTRY of the team

I tried some examples which I have found from StackOverFlow and edited those, but I got stuck adding third TEAMS table to the query.

Here's the one I used

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
FROM DRIVERS
JOIN DRIVERS_IN_TEAMS ON DRIVERS.DRIVER_ID = DRIVERS_IN_TEAMS.DRIVER_ID
WHERE DRIVERS_IN_TEAMS.CAR = 'Ford' AND DRIVERS_IN_TEAMS.END_DATE IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work(join all the tables with the corresponding ids and then you have your conditions):

`SELECT d.FIRST_NAME, d.LAST_NAME, t.COUNTRY FROM DRIVERS d JOIN DRIVERS_IN_TEAMS dit ON dit.DRIVER_ID = d.DRIVER_ID JOIN TEAM t ON dit.TEAM_ID = t.TEAM_ID WHERE dit.END_DATE IS NULL AND dit.CAR = 'Ford'`

Comment: Thank you very much. It was just what I needed!